# Run specific Jasmine test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jasmine

Working with Ruby on Rails. I am trying to determine how to run a particular Jasmine test. Using the following I can run all of them:

`rake jasmine:ci`

but I am trying to specify a specific test. For running Ruby testes you can do the following:

`ruby -Itest <path to test files> -n /"test name here"/`

is there anything like this for the Jasmine rake task?

Answer (score 2):

As of latest release jasmine gem (2.5.0), there is no option to run specific test. But if you use from master http://github.com/jasmine/jasmine-gem there option **spec** with contains specific path test files.

First update your gem file:

```
gem "jasmine", git: 'http://github.com/jasmine/jasmine-gem'
```

then you can run with:

```
env spec=spec/javascripts/your_spec.js rake jasmine:ci
```